# Is it possible to deal with multiple tables on single view with both side validation? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have a question above.

What I want to do is, if a table design is fixed, the entry form is auto generated.
And both client-side and server-side validations are valid.
My image is like the "Force.com".

In order to do so, I think I can't use DataAnnotations. Because before runtime, a table design is not fixed and I can't define any models.
So, if you have any idea to realize it, please let me know.

I understand it's a perverse question, which I try to do without using models in MVC.
But I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about your particular situation but have a look at [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/04/a-basic-t4-template-for-generating-model-metadata-in-asp-net-mvc2.aspx) post about generating data-annotations from T4 templates.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I read the post and understood this is a code generate method. But this isn't a method I'm looking for. Sorry for lack of my explanation. There are two reasons. 1.When a lot of table designs come, this system becomes very big. 2.Each time a table design comes, codes are auto generated. So response seems to be slow. I want to generate various forms in one view code. Anyway, I appreciate your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is that you can use the JQuery Validation in client-side, and make the own validation code in server-side.